# Django QuerySet from one-to-many and from many-to-one

Tags: django, django-queryset, one-to-many, many-to-one

working on a project, where i came to a small problem with QuerySets. (Look at the bottom to see a short diagram of my model structure.) I tried to query some information of a BLOG-Model starting from the Collection-Model. Now is it better to query first the Entrie-Model and find somehow the Collection to afterwards find the Blog-Model and add the information in the end to the Collection? Or is there a better / faster way to get information directly from the parent Model? Normaly it is easy if you just have 1:n->1:n Relations because you can easily follow the foreignkey, but this confuses me.

Here a short overview of my model structure:

```
<--------------- QUERY DIRECTION ----------------
(BLOG) --(1:N)--> (ENTRIE) <--(N:1)-- (COLLECTION)
```

BR, Felix

Answer (score 0):

django's relations works both ways so if you need blog model from collection model you can directly query your Blog model so from your diagram:

```
class Blog:
    entrie = models.ForeignKey(Entrie, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Entrie:
    pass

class Collection:
    entrie = models.ForeignKey(Entrie, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

so your query can be something like if you have not specified any `related_name` attributes on your models relation fields

```
Blog.objects.filter(entrie__collection={your_data})
```